# When I type a "?" in the shell, it becomes a "\?", why?

Tags: shell

I am using Ubuntu on AWS.

And I'm trying to type this:

```
curl https://www.google.com/?1
```

But it always gets this:

```
curl https://www.google.com/\?1
```

There is an extra backslash `\`.

Why this is happening? If I don't enter this after `curl`, then the `\` won't show up. How can `curl` make modifications to my shell?

Comment: wrt *But it always gets this:* how exactly? when you type a question mark a backslash suddenly pops behind it??

Comment: What shell are you using? `echo $SHELL`

Comment: `?` is a glob character.  You almost certainly do not want to pass it unescaped on the command line.  My guess is you are using oh-my-zsh and it is auto escaping it for you.  curl is doing nothing.  This is all your shell.

Comment: @TomZych I got this: `zsh`

Comment: @oguzismail Yes. When I type it or paste it from the clipboard. The backslash comes out automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The question mark has special meaning in the shell. The backslash also has special meaning in the shell: it is an escape character that removes the special meaning from the following character.

It looks like you want to use the question mark simply as a question mark and not with its special meaning. Therefore, you *have* to escape it, i.e. add the backslash to it. Otherwise, the command you are entering would mean something different, and probably not do what you intend to do.

> Why this is happening?

It looks like your shell tries to help you out by adding the backslash for you. If you are 100% sure that you *do* want the special behavior of the question mark, then you can simply delete the backslash.

If you are 100% sure that you *always* know better than the programmer who wrote the shell how the shell works, I am sure, there is some way to turn this feature off.

Note: It might not be the shell *exactly* that does this. It is more likely that the shell supports some hook functions to help with input and you have set up a hook function that does these kinds of modifications for you.

> How can `curl` make modifications to my shell?

It doesn't. Simple basic logic tells you that it *cannot possibly be* `curl` that is doing this, since it happens *while* you are entering the command. Obviously, before you hit enter, `curl` isn't even running, so *clearly* it cannot do anything if it doesn't run.